# what is equivalent to torch.load() in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

I want to know if there is any way to see the parameters of models in tensorflow. there is a command in pytorch i.e. torch.load('/filepath').

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you already have a model saved at `MODEL_PATH`, this should do the trick:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_PATH)
model.summary()
```

[Check this out](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#how_to_save_and_load_a_model) for more info on saving and loading models.

Answer (score 1):

For a prediction context, you can do a

```py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(PATH, compile=True)
```

That works with both .h5 keras models and models on SavedModel format. Otherwise you might have to provide custom metrics and training code you may not have on the prediction context.

For references, check it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model